# Facebook authentication gives me error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use FB API to signing a user. I have source code from here http://pastebin.com/wRJwMRiK

```
 <?php
    // Údaje z https://www.facebook.com/developers/
    define('APP_ID', '221397128027120');
    define('APP_SECRET', 'df8ba9a120b689b577c7b506204a1c9b');
    define('CANVAS_PAGE', 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxx/');
    define('CANVAS_URL', 'http://localhost/xxx/');

    // FB knihovna
    require_once 'facebook.php';

    // Vytvoříme instanci Facebook knihovny
    $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET, ));

    // Získáme ID přihlášeného uživatele
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // Je uživatel přihlášený na Facebooku? resp. máme session?
    if(isset($user)) {
            try {
                    // Zkusíme získat jeho profilová data (nepotřebujeme zatím extended_permission)
                    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                    // Vypíšeme text Exception
                    echo "<strong>" . $e->getMessage() . "</strong>";
                    $user = NULL;
            }
    }

    // Uživatel se odhlásil, odstranil aplikaci...
    if(!is_null($user)) {
            // Získáme logout url
            $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
            // Získáme přihlašovací url
            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
            <head>
                    <title>Moje první aplikace</title>
                    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection,tv" href="screen.css" type="text/css">
            </head>
            <body>
                    <h1>Moje první aplikace</h1>
                    <p>
                            Ahoj
                            <strong>
                            <?php
                            if(!is_null($user))
                                    echo $user_profile["name"];
                            ?>
                            </strong>, jak je? :-)
                    </p>

                    <h2>Přihlásit / odhlásit?</h2>
                    <?php if ($user):
                    ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl;?>">Odhlásit se z Facebooku!</a>
                    <?php else:?>
                    <div>
                            <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>">Přihlásit se na Facebook!</a> (Když už uživatel na FB je, přihlásí ho to do aplikace)
                    </div>
                    <?php endif?>
            </body>
    </html>
```

But it doesn't work it say's me this

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /data16/lokys/html/testGoogle/facebook-sdk/fb2.php:3) in /data16/lokys/html/testGoogle/facebook-sdk/facebook.php on line 49

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /data16/lokys/html/testGoogle/facebook-sdk/fb2.php:3) in /data16/lokys/html/testGoogle/facebook-sdk/facebook.php on line 49
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

The example is [here](http://lokys.cz/testGoogle/facebook-sdk/fb2.php). Could you someone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now, I have an empty space before PHP at the beggining.